# Transaction count after EXECUTE indicates a mismatching number of BEGIN and COMMITS

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have the following error when I run a stored procedure in SQL:

> Transaction count after EXECUTE indicates a mismatching number of BEGIN and COMMIT statements. Previous count = 1, current count = 0.

What does this mean? How could I solve it?

Thank you very much.

```
/****** Object:  StoredProcedure [SingleDirectory].[SPTADIR_EntityIdentification]    Script Date: 26/04/2021 9:37:41 ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
  
ALTER PROCEDURE [SingleDirectory].[SPTADIR_EntityIdentification]  
 -- Add the parameters for the stored procedure here  
 @xmlEntity nvarchar(MAX) = NULL  
AS  

SET XACT_ABORT ON
 BEGIN TRAN 
 BEGIN TRY  

 -- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from  
 -- interfering with SELECT statements.  
 SET NOCOUNT ON;  
  
 
  DECLARE   
   @handle int,  
   @currentDateTime datetime  
  
  -- =============================================  
  --- Protection Against Concurrent Executions    
  -- =============================================  
  
  DECLARE @RC INT  
  DECLARE @message VARCHAR(500)  
  
  SELECT @message = CONVERT(VARCHAR(30), GETDATE(), 121) + ': Try to obtain a lock ..'  
  --RAISERROR(@message, 0, 1) WITH NOWAIT;  
  
  EXEC @RC = sp_getapplock  
   @Resource = '[SingleDirectory].[SPTADIR_EntityIdentification]',  
   @LockMode = 'Exclusive',  
   @LockOwner = 'Transaction',  
   @LockTimeout = 6000 -- 0.1 minute  
  
  IF @RC < 0  
  BEGIN  
   IF @@TRANCOUNT > 0 ROLLBACK TRAN;  
   SELECT @message = CONVERT(VARCHAR(30), GETDATE(), 121) + ': Sorry, could not obtain a lock within the timeout period, return code was ' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(30), @RC) + '.'  
   --RAISERROR(@message, 0, 1) WITH NOWAIT;  
   RETURN @RC  
  END 
  ELSE 
  BEGIN  
   SELECT @message = CONVERT(VARCHAR(30), GETDATE(), 121) + ': AppLock obtained ..'  
   --RAISERROR(@message, 0, 1) WITH NOWAIT;  
  END  
  

  
  -- ******************************  
  -- 1.- Creates tables  
  -- ******************************  
  
  -- TADIR_Entity identification  
  CREATE TABLE [#tmpEntity] (  
   [EntityId] [int] NULL,  
   [EntityType] [int] NOT NULL,  
   [VendorId] [int] NULL,  
   [ProviderEntityId] [varchar](100) COLLATE Latin1_General_100_CI_AS_SC NULL,  
   [FiscalId] [varchar](15) COLLATE Latin1_General_100_CI_AS_SC NULL,  
   [BusinessName] [nvarchar](150) COLLATE Latin1_General_100_CI_AS_SC NULL,  
   [AddressName] [varchar](100) COLLATE Latin1_General_100_CI_AS_SC NULL,  
   [PostalCode] [varchar](10) COLLATE Latin1_General_100_CI_AS_SC NULL,  
   [CityName] [varchar](50) COLLATE Latin1_General_100_CI_AS_SC NULL,  
   [CountryDescr] [varchar](50) COLLATE Latin1_General_100_CI_AS_SC NULL,  
   [StateId] [int] NULL,  
   [PhoneNbr] [varchar](20) COLLATE Latin1_General_100_CI_AS_SC NULL,  
   [SystemId] [int] NULL,  
   [ActiveFlag] [bit] NOT NULL,  
   [ISO2Value] [varchar](2) COLLATE Latin1_General_100_CI_AS_SC NULL,  
   [ISO3Value] [varchar](3) COLLATE Latin1_General_100_CI_AS_SC NULL,  
   [InfoBusinessTypeId] [int] NULL  
  )  
  
  CREATE CLUSTERED INDEX INDEXEntityId ON  [#tmpEntity] (EntityId)  
  CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX INDEXProviderEntityId ON  [#tmpEntity] (ISO2Value, ProviderEntityId, EntityId)  
  CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX INDEXFiscalId ON  [#tmpEntity] (ISO2Value, FiscalId, EntityId)  
  
  -- New TADIR_Entity  
  CREATE TABLE [#tmpEntityInserted] (  
   [EntityId] [int] NULL,  
   [VendorId] [int] NULL,  
   [ProviderEntityId] [varchar](100) COLLATE Latin1_General_100_CI_AS_SC NULL  
  )  
  
  CREATE CLUSTERED INDEX INDEXProviderEntityId ON  [#tmpEntityInserted] (VendorId, ProviderEntityId)  
  
  -- TADIR_EntityIDs   
  CREATE TABLE [#tmpEntityIDs] (  
   [EntityId] [int] NULL,  
   [VendorId] [int] NULL,  
   [ProviderEntityId] [varchar](100) COLLATE Latin1_General_100_CI_AS_SC NULL,  
   [IDType] [tinyint] NULL,  
   [IdentificationValue] [varchar](50) COLLATE Latin1_General_100_CI_AS_SC NULL  
  )  
  
  CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX INDEXProviderEntityId ON  [#tmpEntityIDs] (VendorId, ProviderEntityId)  
  CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX INDEXEntityId ON  [#tmpEntityIDs] (EntityId, IDType)  
  
  -- ******************************  
  -- 2.- Parses XML and inserts into [#tmpEntity] and [#tmpEntityIDs]  
  -- ******************************  
  
  -- XML  
  CREATE TABLE [#tmpEntityXml] (  
   [EntityId] [int] NULL,  
   [EntityType] [int] NOT NULL,  
   [VendorId] [int] NULL,  
   [ProviderEntityId] [varchar](100) COLLATE Latin1_General_100_CI_AS_SC NULL,  
   [FiscalId] [varchar](15) COLLATE Latin1_General_100_CI_AS_SC NULL,  
   [BusinessName] [nvarchar](150) COLLATE Latin1_General_100_CI_AS_SC NULL,  
   [AddressName] [varchar](100) COLLATE Latin1_General_100_CI_AS_SC NULL,  
   [PostalCode] [varchar](10) COLLATE Latin1_General_100_CI_AS_SC NULL,  
   [CityName] [varchar](50) COLLATE Latin1_General_100_CI_AS_SC NULL,  
   [CountryDescr] [varchar](50) COLLATE Latin1_General_100_CI_AS_SC NULL,  
   [StateId] [int] NULL,  
   [PhoneNbr] [varchar](20) COLLATE Latin1_General_100_CI_AS_SC NULL,  
   [SystemId] [int] NULL,  
   [ActiveFlag] [bit] NOT NULL,  
   [ISO2Value] [varchar](2) COLLATE Latin1_General_100_CI_AS_SC NULL,  
   [ISO3Value] [varchar](3) COLLATE Latin1_General_100_CI_AS_SC NULL,  
   [InfoBusinessTypeId] [int] NULL,  
   [IDType] [tinyint] NULL,  
   [IdentificationValue] [varchar](50) COLLATE Latin1_General_100_CI_AS_SC NULL  
  )  
  
  exec sp_xml_preparedocument @handle OUTPUT, @xmlEntity  
      
  INSERT INTO [#tmpEntityXml] (  
     [EntityId],  
     [EntityType],  
     [VendorId],  
     [ProviderEntityId],  
     [FiscalId],  
     [BusinessName],  
     [AddressName],  
     [PostalCode],  
     [CityName],  
     [CountryDescr],  
     [StateId],  
     [PhoneNbr],  
     [SystemId],  
     [ActiveFlag],  
     [ISO2Value],  
     [ISO3Value],  
     [InfoBusinessTypeId],  
     [IDType],  
     [IdentificationValue])  
  SELECT (CASE WHEN EntityId = 0 THEN NULL ELSE EntityId END) AS EntityId,  
    EntityType,   
    (CASE WHEN VendorId = 0 THEN NULL ELSE VendorId END) AS VendorId,  
    (CASE WHEN ProviderEntityId IS NULL THEN NULL ELSE ProviderEntityId END) AS ProviderEntityId,  
    FiscalId,  
    BusinessName,  
    AddressName,  
    PostalCode,  
    CityName,  
    CountryDescr,  
    (CASE WHEN StateId = 0 THEN NULL ELSE StateId END) AS StateId,  
    PhoneNbr,  
    (CASE WHEN SystemId = 0 THEN NULL ELSE SystemId END) AS SystemId,  
    ActiveFlag,  
    ISO2Value,  
    ISO3Value,  
    (CASE WHEN InfoBusinessTypeId = 0 THEN NULL ELSE InfoBusinessTypeId END) AS InfoBusinessTypeId,  
    (CASE WHEN IDType = 0 THEN NULL ELSE IDType END) AS IDType,  
    IdentificationValue             
  FROM OPENXML (@handle, 'ArrayOfIdentificationEntity/IdentificationEntity',3)    
     WITH (  
     EntityId int 'EntityId',  
     EntityType int 'EntityType',  
     VendorId int 'VendorId',  
     ProviderEntityId varchar(100) 'ProviderEntityId',  
     FiscalId varchar(15) 'FiscalId',  
     BusinessName nvarchar(150) 'BusinessName',  
     AddressName varchar(100) 'AddressName',  
     PostalCode varchar(10) 'PostalCode',  
     CityName varchar(50) 'CityName',  
     CountryDescr varchar(50) 'CountryDescr',  
     StateId int 'StateId',  
     PhoneNbr varchar(20) 'PhoneNbr',  
     SystemId int 'SystemId',  
     ActiveFlag bit 'ActiveFlag',  
     ISO2Value varchar(2) 'ISO2Value',  
     ISO3Value varchar(3) 'ISO3Value',  
     InfoBusinessTypeId int 'InfoBusinessTypeId',  
      
     IDType tinyint 'IDType',  
     IdentificationValue varchar(50) 'IdentificationValue')  AS fbEntity  
  
  EXEC sp_xml_removedocument @handle  

  UPDATE [#tmpEntityXml] 
  SET EntityId = [SingleDirectory].[TADIR_Entity].EntityId
  FROM [SingleDirectory].[TADIR_Entity]    
  INNER JOIN [#tmpEntityXml]  
   ON ([SingleDirectory].[TADIR_Entity].[VendorId] = [#tmpEntityXml].[VendorId]
        AND [SingleDirectory].[TADIR_Entity].[ProviderEntityId] = [#tmpEntityXml].[ProviderEntityId] AND [SingleDirectory].[TADIR_Entity].EntityType = [#tmpEntityXml].EntityType) 

    UPDATE [#tmpEntityXml] 
  SET EntityId = [SingleDirectory].[TADIR_Entity].EntityId
  FROM [SingleDirectory].[TADIR_Entity]    
  INNER JOIN [#tmpEntityXml]  
   ON ([SingleDirectory].[TADIR_Entity].[VendorId] = [#tmpEntityXml].[VendorId]
        AND [SingleDirectory].[TADIR_Entity].FiscalId = [#tmpEntityXml].FiscalId AND [SingleDirectory].[TADIR_Entity].EntityType = [#tmpEntityXml].EntityType) 
  
  -- Inserts tmpEntity  
  INSERT INTO [#tmpEntity]   
     ([EntityId], [EntityType], [VendorId], [ProviderEntityId],  
     [FiscalId], [BusinessName], [AddressName], [PostalCode],   
     [CityName], [CountryDescr], [StateId], [PhoneNbr],   
     [SystemId], [ActiveFlag], [ISO2Value], [ISO3Value],   
     [InfoBusinessTypeId])  
  SELECT DISTINCT [EntityId], [EntityType], [VendorId], [ProviderEntityId],  
     [FiscalId], [BusinessName], [AddressName], [PostalCode],  
     [CityName], [CountryDescr], [StateId], [PhoneNbr], [SystemId],  
     [ActiveFlag], [ISO2Value], [ISO3Value], [InfoBusinessTypeId]  
  FROM [#tmpEntityXml]   
  WHERE VendorId IS NOT NULL AND ProviderEntityId IS NOT NULL AND ISO2Value IS NOT NULL   
  
  -- Inserts tmpEntityIDs  
  INSERT INTO [#tmpEntityIDs]   
     ([EntityId], [VendorId], [ProviderEntityId], [IDType], [IdentificationValue])  
  SELECT DISTINCT [EntityId], [VendorId], [ProviderEntityId], [IDType], [IdentificationValue]  
  FROM [#tmpEntityXml]   
  WHERE VendorId IS NOT NULL AND ProviderEntityId IS NOT NULL AND ISO2Value IS NOT NULL AND  
    IDType IS NOT NULL AND IdentificationValue IS NOT NULL  
  
  -- Drops table  
  DROP TABLE [#tmpEntityXml];  
  
  -- ******************************  
  -- 3.- TADIR_Entity  
  -- ******************************  
  
  -- 3.1.- Update TADIR_Entity (when necessary)  
  UPDATE [SingleDirectory].[TADIR_Entity]   
   SET [ActiveFlag] =  [#tmpEntity].[ActiveFlag],  
    [AddressName] = (CASE WHEN  [#tmpEntity].[AddressName] IS NOT NULL THEN  [#tmpEntity].[AddressName] ELSE [SingleDirectory].[TADIR_Entity].[AddressName] END),  
    [BusinessName] = (CASE WHEN  [#tmpEntity].[BusinessName] IS NOT NULL THEN  [#tmpEntity].[BusinessName] ELSE [SingleDirectory].[TADIR_Entity].[BusinessName] END),  
    [CityName] = (CASE WHEN [#tmpEntity].[CityName] IS NOT NULL THEN  [#tmpEntity].[CityName] ELSE [SingleDirectory].[TADIR_Entity].[CityName] END),  
    [CountryDescr] = (CASE WHEN  [#tmpEntity].[CountryDescr] IS NOT NULL THEN  [#tmpEntity].[CountryDescr] ELSE [SingleDirectory].[TADIR_Entity].[CountryDescr] END),  
    [EntityType] =  [#tmpEntity].[EntityType],  
    [FiscalId] = (CASE WHEN [#tmpEntity].[FiscalId] IS NOT NULL THEN  [#tmpEntity].[FiscalId] ELSE [SingleDirectory].[TADIR_Entity].[FiscalId] END),  
    [ISO2Value] = (CASE WHEN  [#tmpEntity].[ISO2Value] IS NOT NULL THEN  [#tmpEntity].[ISO2Value] ELSE [SingleDirectory].[TADIR_Entity].[ISO2Value] END),  
    [ISO3Value] = (CASE WHEN [#tmpEntity].[ISO3Value] IS NOT NULL THEN  [#tmpEntity].[ISO3Value] ELSE [SingleDirectory].[TADIR_Entity].[ISO3Value] END),  
    [InfoBusinessTypeId] = (CASE WHEN [#tmpEntity].[InfoBusinessTypeId] IS NOT NULL THEN  [#tmpEntity].[InfoBusinessTypeId] ELSE [SingleDirectory].[TADIR_Entity].[InfoBusinessTypeId] END),  
    [PhoneNbr] = (CASE WHEN  [#tmpEntity].[PhoneNbr] IS NOT NULL THEN  [#tmpEntity].[PhoneNbr] ELSE [SingleDirectory].[TADIR_Entity].[PhoneNbr] END),  
    [PostalCode] = (CASE WHEN  [#tmpEntity].[PostalCode] IS NOT NULL THEN  [#tmpEntity].[PostalCode] ELSE [SingleDirectory].[TADIR_Entity].[PostalCode] END),  
    [ProviderEntityId] = (CASE WHEN [#tmpEntity].[ProviderEntityId] IS NOT NULL THEN [#tmpEntity].[ProviderEntityId] ELSE [SingleDirectory].[TADIR_Entity].[ProviderEntityId] END),  
    [StateId] = (CASE WHEN  [#tmpEntity].[StateId] NOT LIKE 0 THEN  [#tmpEntity].[StateId] ELSE [SingleDirectory].[TADIR_Entity].[StateId] END),  
    [SystemId] = (CASE WHEN [SingleDirectory].[TADIR_Entity].[SystemId] IS NULL THEN  [#tmpEntity].[SystemId] ELSE [SingleDirectory].[TADIR_Entity].[SystemId] END),  
    [VendorId] = [#tmpEntity].[VendorId],  
    [UpdateDate] = GETUTCDATE()  
  FROM [SingleDirectory].[TADIR_Entity]      
  INNER JOIN [#tmpEntity]  
   ON ([SingleDirectory].[TADIR_Entity].[EntityId] = [#tmpEntity].[EntityId])  
  WHERE ([SingleDirectory].[TADIR_Entity].[ActiveFlag] IS NULL AND [#tmpEntity].[ActiveFlag] IS NOT NULL) OR ([SingleDirectory].[TADIR_Entity].[ActiveFlag] IS NOT NULL AND [#tmpEntity].[ActiveFlag] IS NULL) OR [SingleDirectory].[TADIR_Entity].[ActiveFlag]
 NOT LIKE  [#tmpEntity].[ActiveFlag]  
     OR ( [#tmpEntity].[AddressName] IS NOT NULL AND ([SingleDirectory].[TADIR_Entity].[AddressName] IS NULL OR [SingleDirectory].[TADIR_Entity].[AddressName] NOT LIKE  [#tmpEntity].[AddressName]))  
     OR ( [#tmpEntity].[BusinessName] IS NOT NULL AND ([SingleDirectory].[TADIR_Entity].[BusinessName] IS NULL OR [SingleDirectory].[TADIR_Entity].[BusinessName] NOT LIKE  [#tmpEntity].[BusinessName]))  
     OR ( [#tmpEntity].[CityName] IS NOT NULL AND ([SingleDirectory].[TADIR_Entity].[CityName] IS NULL OR [SingleDirectory].[TADIR_Entity].[CityName] NOT LIKE  [#tmpEntity].[CityName]))  
     OR ( [#tmpEntity].[CountryDescr] IS NOT NULL AND ([SingleDirectory].[TADIR_Entity].[CountryDescr] IS NULL OR [SingleDirectory].[TADIR_Entity].[CountryDescr] NOT LIKE  [#tmpEntity].[CountryDescr]))  
     OR ( [SingleDirectory].[TADIR_Entity].[EntityType] IS NULL AND [#tmpEntity].[EntityType] IS NOT NULL) OR ([SingleDirectory].[TADIR_Entity].[EntityType] IS NOT NULL AND [#tmpEntity].[EntityType] IS NULL) OR [SingleDirectory].[TADIR_Entity].[EntityType] NOT LIKE  [#tmpEntity].[EntityType]  
     OR ( [#tmpEntity].[FiscalId] IS NOT NULL AND ([SingleDirectory].[TADIR_Entity].[FiscalId] IS NULL OR [SingleDirectory].[TADIR_Entity].[FiscalId] NOT LIKE  [#tmpEntity].[FiscalId]))  
     OR ( [#tmpEntity].[ISO2Value] IS NOT NULL AND ([SingleDirectory].[TADIR_Entity].[ISO2Value] IS NULL OR [SingleDirectory].[TADIR_Entity].[ISO2Value] NOT LIKE  [#tmpEntity].[ISO2Value]))  
     OR ( [#tmpEntity].[ISO3Value] IS NOT NULL AND ([SingleDirectory].[TADIR_Entity].[ISO3Value] IS NULL OR [SingleDirectory].[TADIR_Entity].[ISO3Value] NOT LIKE  [#tmpEntity].[ISO3Value]))  
     OR ( [#tmpEntity].[InfoBusinessTypeId] IS NOT NULL AND ([SingleDirectory].[TADIR_Entity].[InfoBusinessTypeId] IS NULL OR [SingleDirectory].[TADIR_Entity].[InfoBusinessTypeId] NOT LIKE [#tmpEntity].[InfoBusinessTypeId]))  
     OR ( [#tmpEntity].[PhoneNbr] IS NOT NULL AND ([SingleDirectory].[TADIR_Entity].[PhoneNbr] IS NULL OR [SingleDirectory].[TADIR_Entity].[PhoneNbr] NOT LIKE  [#tmpEntity].[PhoneNbr]))  
     OR ( [#tmpEntity].[PostalCode] IS NOT NULL AND ([SingleDirectory].[TADIR_Entity].[PostalCode] IS NULL OR [SingleDirectory].[TADIR_Entity].[PostalCode] NOT LIKE  [#tmpEntity].[PostalCode]))  
     OR ( [SingleDirectory].[TADIR_Entity].[ProviderEntityId] IS NULL AND [#tmpEntity].[ProviderEntityId] IS NOT NULL) OR ([SingleDirectory].[TADIR_Entity].[ProviderEntityId] IS NOT NULL AND [#tmpEntity].[ProviderEntityId] IS NULL) OR [SingleDirectory].[TADIR_Entity].[ProviderEntityId] NOT LIKE  [#tmpEntity].[ProviderEntityId]  
     OR ( [#tmpEntity].[StateId] NOT LIKE 0 AND ([SingleDirectory].[TADIR_Entity].[StateId] IS NULL OR [SingleDirectory].[TADIR_Entity].[StateId] NOT LIKE  [#tmpEntity].[StateId]))  
     OR ([SingleDirectory].[TADIR_Entity].[SystemId] IS NULL)  
     OR ( [SingleDirectory].[TADIR_Entity].[VendorId] IS NULL AND [#tmpEntity].[VendorId] IS NOT NULL) OR ( [SingleDirectory].[TADIR_Entity].[VendorId] IS NOT NULL AND [#tmpEntity].[VendorId] IS NULL) OR [SingleDirectory].[TADIR_Entity].[VendorId] NOT LIKE [#tmpEntity].[VendorId]  
  
  -- 3.2.- INSERTS into TADIR_Entity not identified emtotoes  
  SET @currentDateTime = GETUTCDATE()  
  
  -- INSERT INTO TADIR_Entity  
  INSERT INTO [SingleDirectory].[TADIR_Entity] ([EntityType],  
              [VendorId],  
              [ProviderEntityId],  
              [FiscalId],  
              [BusinessName],  
              [AddressName],  
              [PostalCode],  
              [CityName],  
              [CountryDescr],  
              [StateId],  
              [PhoneNbr],  
              [SystemId],  
              [ActiveFlag],  
              [ISO2Value],  
              [ISO3Value],  
              [InfoBusinessTypeId],  
              [CreationDate],  
              [UpdateDate])  
  OUTPUT INSERTED.EntityId, INSERTED.VendorId, INSERTED.ProviderEntityId INTO [#tmpEntityInserted]  
  SELECT [#tmpEntity].[EntityType],  
    [#tmpEntity].[VendorId],  
    [#tmpEntity].[ProviderEntityId],  
    [#tmpEntity].[FiscalId],  
    [#tmpEntity].[BusinessName],  
    [#tmpEntity].[AddressName],  
    [#tmpEntity].[PostalCode],  
    [#tmpEntity].[CityName],  
    [#tmpEntity].[CountryDescr],  
    [#tmpEntity].[StateId],  
    [#tmpEntity].[PhoneNbr],  
    [#tmpEntity].[SystemId],  
    [#tmpEntity].[ActiveFlag],  
    [#tmpEntity].[ISO2Value],  
    [#tmpEntity].[ISO3Value],  
    [#tmpEntity].[InfoBusinessTypeId],  
    @currentDateTime,  
    @currentDateTime    
  FROM [#tmpEntity]  
  WHERE [#tmpEntity].[EntityId] IS NULL  
  
  -- UPDATE [#tmpEntityXml].[EntityId]  
  UPDATE [#tmpEntity]  
  SET [EntityId] = [#tmpEntityInserted].[EntityId]  
  FROM  [#tmpEntity]  
  INNER JOIN [#tmpEntityInserted]  
   ON ([#tmpEntity].[ProviderEntityId] = [#tmpEntityInserted].[ProviderEntityId]   
    AND [#tmpEntity].[VendorId] = [#tmpEntityInserted].[VendorId])  
  
    
  -- 3.3.- Update EntityId ON [#tmpEntityIDs]  
  UPDATE [#tmpEntityIDs]  
  SET [EntityId] = [#tmpEntity].[EntityId]  
  FROM [#tmpEntityIDs]  
  INNER JOIN [#tmpEntity]   
   ON ([#tmpEntityIDs].[VendorId] = [#tmpEntity].[VendorId]   
    AND [#tmpEntityIDs].[ProviderEntityId] = [#tmpEntity].[ProviderEntityId]  
    AND [#tmpEntityIDs].[EntityId] IS NULL)  
  
  -- ******************************  
  -- 4.- TADIR_EntityIDs  
  -- ******************************  
  
  -- 4.1.- DELETE old values  
  DELETE [SingleDirectory].[TADIR_EntityIDs]  
  FROM [SingleDirectory].[TADIR_EntityIDs]   
  INNER JOIN [#tmpEntity]   
   ON ([SingleDirectory].[TADIR_EntityIDs].[EntityId] = [#tmpEntity].[EntityId])  
  LEFT JOIN [#tmpEntityIDs]  
   ON ([SingleDirectory].[TADIR_EntityIDs].[EntityId] = [#tmpEntityIDs].[EntityId]  
    AND [SingleDirectory].[TADIR_EntityIDs].[IDType] = [#tmpEntityIDs].[IDType])  
  WHERE [#tmpEntityIDs].[EntityId] IS NULL  
  
  -- 4.2.- UPDATE values  
  UPDATE [SingleDirectory].[TADIR_EntityIDs]  
  SET [IdentificationValue] = [#tmpEntityIDs].[IdentificationValue]  
  FROM [SingleDirectory].[TADIR_EntityIDs]   
  INNER JOIN [#tmpEntityIDs]  
    ON ([#tmpEntityIDs].[EntityId] = [SingleDirectory].[TADIR_EntityIDs].[EntityId] AND   
     [#tmpEntityIDs].[IDType] = [SingleDirectory].[TADIR_EntityIDs].[IDType])  
  WHERE [#tmpEntityIDs].[IdentificationValue] NOT LIKE [SingleDirectory].[TADIR_EntityIDs].[IdentificationValue]  
    
  -- 4.3.- INSERT values   
  INSERT INTO [SingleDirectory].[TADIR_EntityIDs] ([EntityId],   
              [IDType],   
              [IdentificationValue])  
  SELECT [#tmpEntityIDs].[EntityId],   
    [#tmpEntityIDs].[IDType],   
    [#tmpEntityIDs].[IdentificationValue]  
  FROM [#tmpEntityIDs]   
  LEFT JOIN [SingleDirectory].[TADIR_EntityIDs]   
   ON ([#tmpEntityIDs].[EntityId] = [SingleDirectory].[TADIR_EntityIDs].[EntityId]   
    AND [#tmpEntityIDs].[IDType] = [SingleDirectory].[TADIR_EntityIDs].[IDType])  
  WHERE [SingleDirectory].[TADIR_EntityIDs].[EntityId] IS NULL  
  
  -- ******************************  
  -- 5.- Loads the return results.  
  -- ******************************  
  
  SELECT DISTINCT [SingleDirectory].[TADIR_Entity].*, [SingleDirectory].[TADIR_EntityIDs].[IDType], [SingleDirectory].[TADIR_EntityIDs].[IdentificationValue]  
  FROM [SingleDirectory].[TADIR_Entity]  
  INNER JOIN [#tmpEntity]  
   ON ([SingleDirectory].[TADIR_Entity].[EntityId] = [#tmpEntity].[EntityId] )  
  LEFT JOIN [SingleDirectory].[TADIR_EntityIDs]  
   ON ([SingleDirectory].[TADIR_Entity].[EntityId] = [SingleDirectory].[TADIR_EntityIDs].[EntityId])  
  WHERE [#tmpEntity].[EntityId] IS NOT NULL  
  
  -- ******************************  
  -- 6.- Free memory  
  -- ******************************  
  DROP INDEX INDEXEntityId ON [#tmpEntity]  
  DROP INDEX INDEXProviderEntityId ON [#tmpEntity]  
  DROP INDEX INDEXFiscalId ON [#tmpEntity]  
  DROP TABLE [#tmpEntity]   
    
  DROP INDEX INDEXProviderEntityId ON [#tmpEntityInserted]  
  DROP TABLE [#tmpEntityInserted]   
    
  DROP INDEX INDEXProviderEntityId ON [#tmpEntityIDs]  
  DROP INDEX INDEXEntityId ON [#tmpEntityIDs]  
  DROP TABLE [#tmpEntityIDs]   
  

 END TRY  
  
 BEGIN CATCH  
  IF @@TRANCOUNT > 0  
        ROLLBACK TRAN;
   INSERT INTO [Log].[tasip_errorlogdb]
                  (errorcode,
                   errorstatusvalue,
                   procedurevalue,
                   descriptionmessagetext,
                   wrongtracecode,
                   date)
      VALUES      (Error_number(),
                   Error_state(),
                   Error_procedure(),
                   Error_message(),
                   Error_line(),
                   Getutcdate());
                   
  SELECT ERROR_MESSAGE() AS ErrorMessage;        
 END CATCH   
 
   IF @@TRANCOUNT > 0  
    COMMIT TRAN;
```

Comment: It means exactly what it says, you've started more transactions than you have committed. You may need to check whether you already have an open transaction before you open another. Your SP is both too complex, and has too many nested SP's for anyone to be able to actually find it for you.

Comment: I will point out two side things: `XACT_ABORT` will automatically rollback in the event of an error, and you should use `.nodes` instead of `sp_xml_preparedocument` and `OPENXML`

Comment: Just an idea, if  you manually stopped the execution via the Big Red Button in ssms, the transaction is neither committed or rolled back. It remains struck. You have to do a manual commit or rollback.  Just a quick question, why do you the commit outside of the try block?